# How to find the angles for a truss.

Tags: trigonometry

I have been solving truss questions, and for this question, I have no idea of how I can solve part (b):
[image]

I found the answers for (a), but I can't solve the forces for point E, since I cannot find the angle of it.
Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is point A fixed to the wall or just resting against the wall? How much does the truss weigh? Is the weight of a rod is proportional to its length? How much do the thingys at A and B weigh?

Comment: Point A is resting on the wall. The question does not give any information about the weight of the truss

Comment: Nor the length of any member

Comment: I'm not sure, but if $\overline {AD} = \overline {DE}$, then you would have a 45-45-90 triangle; hence the angle would be $45^{\circ}$ at $E$.  Then you would have the forces at $E$ equal to $350 \sin 45^{\circ}$ and $350 \cos 45^{\circ}$.